# Changing App name in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

Is there anyway to change the app name in iTunes connect. It took me 3 or 4 goes to try and upload my app the first time and somehow I made a bit of a mess of it.

iTunes Connect is now telling that the app name has been used and cannot be reused. Is there anyway around this ?

The actual app name that appears on the device is correct, I edited this on the info.plist.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: Anyone looking to edit their app name should see this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973956/how-to-change-app-name-in-itunes-connect/19163971#19163971

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of right now, no. You can change the App's name when you submit an update, or simply create a new App in iTunes connect. You might want to submit a feature request to Apple at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Sorry Reed, just read your answer properly, ignore my previous comment. That really sucks, I'll try submitting a bugreport, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

From the Deleting an App section of Apple's [iTunes Connect Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf) guide:

> If you delete your app, you cannot reuse your SKU or app
>   name in the same account again, and you cannot restore the app you
>   have deleted. If you have uploaded a binary or set up this app for the
>   iAd network, your Bundle ID cannot be reused.

Next they mention this:

> If you are selling your app to another developer for their own
>   distribution and need to remove it from your iTunes Connect account,
>   we recommend that you use App Delete so that the app’s **name will be
>   freed for their use**.

So if you are more attached to your app name than your developer account you could start a new one and get the name back.

In [Build and Analyze 93](http://5by5.tv/buildanalyze/93) Marco discusses some reasons and logistics of having 2 developer accounts. As I remember: Apple does not allow 2 accounts with one tax ID but if you have your personal and an LLC for instance you'll be able to setup multiple.

Answer (score 2):

1. If your application is in Waiting for review mode then you can change your app name inside Viewdetails->Metadata and Uploads->app name
2. If your application is in live mode then you need to submit new version with new name.

Comment: But in my case , My application get approved iTunes-connect .Now, i want rename my app name . Can i do this . let me know. As i know after get approved app name lock by iTunesConnect and lock .

Comment: Hey..I think no. You need to create again new app for different name and re upload on store. Also remove all territory for live app if you want to remove it from app store.

Comment: You can change it by releasing a new version.  When you create a new version, then go to "App Information" you will be able to change the name.  It will stay the old name until this new version is approved by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can edit it when in an 'editable state', but I have not tried it yet.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/