# Change name on an app already in app store?

Tags: iphone

I have just got my first app on AppStore but realise that I should add a word to the title to make it more visible.

Is this possible?

If not, what is recommended in situatios lime this and what about the current title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can change it if you submit an update.

[Changing App name in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784967/changing-app-name-in-itunes-connect)