# How to Change App name in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios5, ios4, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-sdk

Is there anyway to change the app name in iTunes connect.Previously we followed the the below procedure to change app name,
1. Log in to Itunes Connect
2. Click "Manage applications"
3. Click on your app
4. Click "View details"
5. Click on Edit (At the right of "Version information")
6. Edit your app name.

But currently it is not working, Is there is any way to change app name.
Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 31):

After some confusion I managed to change my app name (while it was in status 'Prepare for Upload' - not sure if this works for other statuses):

1. Log in to Itunes Connect
2. Click "Manage applications"
3. Click on your app
4. Click "View details" under your current version
5. Click on Edit next to "Metadata and Uploads"

And then you can edit the name.

Comment: This doesn't work after the app has been approved.  You need to follow atrljoe's advice below in that case.

Answer (score 23):

The only way you can edit a App Name (assuming the app has been approved) is by creating a new version, at that point you can modify it.

Apple has removed the tables that once referenced what could be updated during what statuses. Now Apple has outlined exactly what **CAN** be change while the app is in the 'Ready for Sale' status. Anything else will require a new version to be created.

> You can change the following store metadata while an app’s version has
>   the “Ready for Sale” status:
>
> - Copyright, Routing App Coverage File
> - Description, What’s New in this Version
> - Support URL, Marketing URL, and Privacy Policy URL
> - App Store Contact Information Language support, including adding new languages
>     and changing the default language
> - EULA

Source: [Apple iOS Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppMetadata.html)

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions, it helps lot :)

Comment: Hi.. Will this change of name reflect in the current version also? If I have 2.0 ready for sale with app name 'X', will changing app name to 'Y' in 2.1 change the app name in v2.0 also?

Comment: what about changing the name before the app is approved or before even uploading the .ipa file?

Comment: @atrljoe Is it required to upload new build if we just want to change the app name?

Answer (score 19):

Its place on the renewed iTunes Connect interface is under 'Versions' tab:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why so many people go around saying this isn't possible. The input field is right there (as you showed in your nice screenshot). Glad to know some more people can see the input field........ The bold red line was priceless!!

Comment: I don't see this line.

Comment: Same, this input does not appear for me on the page despite the app's state being "waiting for review".

Comment: Update to the above: seems like there's a particular UI issue with App Store Connect. If you have your "display element size" set to higher than the default, then most of the App Store Connect interface is hidden (not scrollable) at default zoom. Zoom out and it all appears, including the "App Info" tab that takes you to the name field. Oy...

Answer (score 4):

To rename existing application on App Store you can create **New Version** and
then enter **app-name** in `Name` field.

This name will be displayed now as the name of your app on the App Store. This can't be longer than **`255`** characters.

Comment: Now it's 50 characters.

Comment: Now it's limited to 30 characters haha.

Answer (score 1):

There would be some confusion around that, the reason is that the name you put on the app store (on iTunesConnect) can be different from the name given within Xcode (under build settings)..

So if your app name is displayed properly on the app store, but when you download it, the name is different, it's because Apple doesn't apply the name given on iTunesConnect to the binary that people download..

Which means you have to recompile and reupload as new version..

Answer (score 1):

The way to change your App 'Name' or 'Subtitle' seems to have changed slightly.

First need to create a 'new version' of your app, use the option: "+ VERSION OR PLATFORM" (shown in the image below), then after saving that new version, you can click on the "App Information" (shown in the image below), and in that form you now can edit the "Name" and "Subtitle" (which will both be reviewed by Apple before your new version if the app becomes available on the App store).

This new name and subtitle will be used for the new version of your app on the app store.

[image: App enter image description here]