# Changing Apps name in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios

My App is in the state of prepare for submission.

I have changed its name under the tab Versions -> Name.

However when I go back to My Apps section where it list all the apps it shows me the previous name and only when I select the App it shows me the changed name.

Kindly tell me how the name change can be reflected everywhere.

Comment: this may help u. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973956/how-to-change-app-name-in-itunes-connect

Comment: The name changes were updated after a days time.