# Change bundle ID after uploading app on iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Recently i have uploaded application on iTunes successfully. Now my application is in `Ready for Sale` status.

However I made a mistake in `Bundle ID`. My client has requested that he wants to change the bundle id.

So I plan to create another app with new bundle id and unpublish the old one.

**Couple of questions:**

1. iTunes does not allow me to create another app with same name. (would it allow me if I unpublish the old app?)
2. Would there be any issue in apple review when I submit the new app for review? (as i had an old app which i unpublished)

**Note:** It has been only 2 days since the app has gone `“ready for sale”`

Comment: @Pisush -: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973956/how-to-change-app-name-in-itunes-connect . And you can not change bundle id.

Comment: So how can i change bundle ID? How can i delete app from iTunes ?

Comment: Read apple guide lines https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/Properties.html

Comment: How can i delete app from iTunes ? @Arasuvel

Comment: It was there in the doc itself : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW1

Comment: there is no option to delete app.

Comment: @Maulik  So is there no any alternate solution??

Comment: No.... not possible.....

Comment: @Maulik Can you read my question again ?

Comment: @Piyush not possible. Previous iTunes version it's possible.

Comment: All developer link provide wrong info. New itunes you can transfer app only

Comment: Can you describe in detail ? @Maulik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Questions of answer:**

1. iTunes does not allow me to create another app with same name. (would it allow me if I unpublish the old app?)

   **Ans.** Yes, first unpublish app then create another app with the same name **OR** First old app new version create and change app name then create the new app with the same name.
2. Would there be any issue in apple review when I submit the new app for review? (as i had an old app which i unpublished)

   **Ans.** No, there be no issue in apple review.

Comment: For question 1: I think you would need to delete the app and not just unpublish

Comment: First part worked. Putting new app on review now. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Once app publish then you don't delete app only unpublished AND  okay then apple have no issue with new app