# Changing app store application name

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to release another application with the same name by changing old application name.
I know that only way to change old application name is by releasing the update.

But will that allow me to use the same name to release the other app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change app name in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383593/change-app-name-in-app-store)

Answer (score 1):

If your asking  if you can change the name of an application,
A Google search will present the following as the top two hits

[Changing App name in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784967/changing-app-name-in-itunes-connect)

[How to Change App name in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973956/how-to-change-app-name-in-itunes-connect)

> You can change the following store metadata while an app’s version has
>   the “Ready for Sale” status:
>
> Copyright, Routing App Coverage File Description, What’s New in this
>   Version Support URL, Marketing URL, and Privacy Policy URL App Store
>   Contact Information Language support, including adding new languages
>   and changing the default language EULA

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what i actually want to know is once the app name is changed to Some thing else, will i be able to use old name for some other app.